# How to store the content of an InkCanvas in a List

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm implementing an undo/redo feature to an `InkCanvas`, so I need to save the content of the `InkCanvas` in a list (not a file) every time it gets modified. I'm currently saving it in an `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` but since it needs to be an instance I can't use it in a list. Is there a way I could store more than one content and retrieve when necessary?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement of undo/redo feature, you can use [`AddStroke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Methods) and [`DeleteSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_DeleteSelected) method to add or delete the stroke that you want to undo or redo. Here is my code, you can have a reference.

```
private List<InkStroke> undoList = new List<InkStroke>();
private void Undo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> inkList = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
    if (inkList.Count > 0)
    {
        InkStroke undoStroke = inkList[inkList.Count - 1];
        undoStroke.Selected = true;
        undoList.Add(undoStroke.Clone());
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.DeleteSelected();
    }
}

private void Redo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (undoList.Count > 0)
    {
        InkStroke redoStroke = undoList[undoList.Count - 1];
        inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStroke(redoStroke);
        undoList.Remove(redoStroke);
    }
}
```